# Custom event handler not getting initialized

Tags: c#

Following is the Code i am using

```
class ImpersonatedTab : System.Windows.Forms.TabPage  
    {
        Credentials _cred = new Credentials();

        public delegate void Savesetting(TabData Tb);
        public event Savesetting TriggerSaveSetting;


        public ImpersonatedTab(TabData tb)
        {          
            ........
        }

        private void SaveData()
        {
            TriggerSaveSetting(_tabdata);
        }

       private Onclick()
       {
         SaveData();
       }


     }
```

When i call Onclick function within ImpersonatedTab class it returns error saying TriggerSaveSetting is null

I initialize this call like

```
ImpersonatedTab Tab = new ImpersonatedTab(tb);
Tab.TriggerSaveSetting += new ImpersonatedTab.Savesetting(Tab_TriggerSaveSetting);
```

i have created events earlier, but am not able to figure out whats wrong with this one.. i am sure should be some silly mistake.

Comment: Could you by any chance be calling the `SaveData` method from within the `ImpersonatedTab` constructor? There where you put those `....`.

Comment: A good manner is to always check if the event is not null:
private void SaveData()
        {
            if(TriggerSaveSetting != null)
                TriggerSaveSetting(_tabdata);
        }

Comment: @zavaz: I'd prefer initializing the delegate with an empty anonymous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible case where this could happen is if you try to call the event from within the constructor of the `ImpersonatedTab` class. There where you put those `...`. Also it is a good practice to check if the event handler has been initialized before calling it.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
    public delegate void Savesetting(TabData Tb);
    private Savesetting saveSettingDlg;

    public event Savesetting TriggerSaveSetting {
        add { saveSettingDlg += value; }
        remove { saveSettingDlg -= value; }
    }

    private void SaveData() {
        var handler = saveSettingDlg;
        if (handler != null) handler(_tabdata);
    }
```

You can now set a breakpoint on the *add* accessor and SaveData() and verify that event subscription is working correctly.  If you *do* see the add accessor getting called but still get a null for *handler* then there's a problem with the object reference.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to invoke the TriggerSaveSetting event handlers *before* any handler was attached to it. Make sure, to check, the event has been some handlers attached:

```
private void OnTriggerSaveSetting(_tabdata)
{
    if (TriggerSaveSetting != null)
        TriggerSaveSetting(_tabdata);
}
```